# Openpyxl reads wrongly xslx file

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am using this code to load xslx file and I'm receiving 1 row with over 1k. Does anyone know how to handle it?

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

wb= openpyxl.load_workbook(r'path')
df = pd.DataFrame(wb)
print(df)
```

outcome:
0  (, , , ,

[1 rows x 1452 columns]

Comment: y r u reading it with openpyxl and not pandas directly?

Comment: try using [`pd.read_excel(r'path')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) instead..?

Comment: I cannot install xlrd on this machine.

Comment: @Michał you're trying to read the workbook itself, not the data. An Excel Workbook contains multiple sheets and the data you want to load probably *doesn't* start at A1 - there may be hidden rows, titles, headers etc

Comment: Covered by https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking code straight from here:

https://www.soudegesu.com/en/post/python/pandas-with-openpyxl/

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'path.xlsx')
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
data = ws.values
columns = next(data)[0:]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Column_A Column_B
0       100      Abc
1       200      Def
2       300      Ghj
3       400      Ijk
```

---

If you would like to loop through multiple sheets, you can modify it like this:

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'path.xlsx')
for ws in wb.sheetnames:
    print("Name of sheet: ", ws)
    ws = wb[ws]
    data = ws.values
    columns = next(data)[0:]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
Name of sheet:  Sheet1
   Column_A Column_B
0       100      Abc
1       200      Def
2       300      Ghj
3       400      Ijk
Name of sheet:  Sheet2
   Column_A Column_B
0       500      lmn
1       600      opq
2       700      rst
3       800      uvw
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! Do I need to always put inside ws=wb['Sheet_name'] exact sheet name or it can be somehow automated?

Comment: @Michał an Excel file contains *multiple* sheets and the data can appear at any point in the sheet itself. `DataFrame` can't guess what to read

Comment: @Michał You can get the `sheetnames` from the workbook, and then you can make it loop through them with the same bit of code.

Comment: I mean I want to read to database 5 excel files and later handle them. They have only one sheet inside them so that's why I was asking if there is a way to get first sheetname automatically.

Comment: @Michał I have added a looped version to the code, where the actual name that the sheet has is not needed. If the file just contains one sheet, then it will just go over the file once.